# Does Hextech's "reroll" function consider the skin type as result?

Tags: league-of-legends

If I reroll 3 skins of the same type, say 3 legendary skin shards, will I get a different legendary skin shard, or literally any random skin?

Comment: good question, not that i've ever even had one leg. skin let alone 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find any offical FAQ answer on this, but obviously rerolling 3 legendary shards does not automatically result in a permanent legendary skin. Here's a [counter-example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3EDZCaj13w) where the player is rerolling *Alpha Battle Skarner*, *Battlecast Prime Cho'Gath*, and *Project: Yi* (all of these are legendaries) and it gives a permanent *Dragonwing Corki* (regular permanent skin).

Also, this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/4ar8r7/this_is_what_happens_when_you_reroll_3_legendary/) and [LoL Boards post](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/gameplay-balance/G6GtwAXw-crafting-legendary-shards) tell that rerolling skin shards is random. You can get a 520RP skin from 3 Leggy's and vice versa. This is, of course, all experience-based, but finding counter-examples is enough to answer this question.

So my advice would be to disenchant high-value skin shards into orange essence, and to reroll the low-value skin (520 and 750RP) into permanent skin.